# Notation for weights of Edges in Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory, notation

I got a question regarding the used notation of weight on the edges of Graphs (I'm quite new to Graph Theory, so don't judge).
[image]

How would you express the weights of a edge.
For example say that the weight of the Edge $(K_1,K_2)$ is 5 (or whatever).
Is there a way to express this other than through plain text.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Something like $\omega_{12} = 5$ ? More generally define $\omega : E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ so you have a weight $\omega_{ij}$ for each edge $(i,j)\in E$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straightforward approach is to define the *weighting function* from $E$ (the edges) to $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{N}$, or whatever other field you want to use for the weights.

In my experience this function is usually called $w$. (Someone suggested in the comments to use $\omega$, which I find surprising).

Comment: Answered my question in combination with Kuifje's comment, thanks